# Upload CSV file of 50MB in size to a REST endpoint in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS. I am able to convert the table data to CSV and store that in a file and i have used third party plugins to send that whole data as string to a REST  end point.

But now the requirement has been changed to upload the whole csv data as a file to REST end point.

Can you please help me or guide me with a script code as how upload can be done in general. I have searched a lot and all i see is download the files using VB C# code but not upload.

Comment: What do you mean by REST end point ?

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this by using curl and calling the script task in SSIS.

Created a bat file with the below command which invokes the Config.txt and the response or errors will be written into ErrorLog.txt

curl -K Config.txt > ErrorLog.txt

Config.txt has the below content

-w "|response-%{http_code}"
-H Content-Type:text/plain
-u UserName and Password
--url https://httpbin.org
--data-binary @C:\Users\Desktop\SSISWork\Connect.json

When the package is executed in SSIS then the script task gets invoked which calls the curl and the rest of the processing happens.